# Cannot resolve method handleResponse using observable

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, observable

I have a function `loadProfile()`

```
private void loadProfile() {
        mSubscriptions.add(RetrofitClient.getRetrofit(mToken).getProfile(mEmail)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::handleError));
}
```

which calls `handleResponse`

```
private void handleResponse(Response response, User user) {
     //some code
}
```

And `handleResponse` is defined in my `Api` class like this:

```
@GET("Users/{id}")
Observable<retrofit2.Response<User>> getProfile(@Path("id") String id);
```

And I am getting `cannot resolve method handleResponse` in `loadProfile()`
I checked parameter types as many similar questions suggest, but can't find the problem. I hope I provided everything necessary to find the problem.

Comment: handleResponse requires parameters which you are not passing when you are calling it from loadProfile and that's why cannot resolve the method error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your return type is `Observable<Response<User>>`

I think your method should be

```
    private void handleResponse(Response<User> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            User user = response.body()
        } else {
            // some code
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how will I access `response` object and `user` object? And what is `response:`?

Comment: Sorry. Updated the code. That was Kotlin sytnax. Just a habit. You can get your object from `body()` if you want to handle it yourself. Also i can suggest to use `Single` instead of `Observable`.

Comment: Btw, is there a way of passing more objects?